# Asterisk Expansion in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, parameters

I am writing a batch script that is checking if a passed in parameter (for a git branch) matches a specific type of branch. Here is the code I have:

```
@echo off
if %Branch% == "refs/topics/*" (
    echo yes
)
if not %Branch% == "refs/topics/*" (
     echo no
)
```

This is just a simple example of what it's supposed to do within the if/else condition branches, but the problem that I'm facing is when I'm passing a parameter that's supposed to go into the "yes" branch, it still goes into the "no" branch. Here is the parameter that I'm passing: refs/topics/tester

Which, theoretically, it should be the same as refs/topics/ with the asterisk expansion. What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it to check correctly?

Comment: The `==` is comparing a literal string, the asterisk is just that, not a wildcard.

Comment: `%Branch%` is a variable (currently undefined - so your `if` should give a syntax error). A parameter would be referenced with `%1`

Comment: If the variable `Branch` does have a value, it will also need surrounding quotes assigned to that value for the `IF` comparison to be true.

Answer (score 2):

`IF` comparisons in batch files are literal.  Everything on the left must match everything to the right, character for character. The asterisks cannot be used as a wildcard.

Assuming somewhere in your batch file you actually assigned a passed argument to the variable branch, your code should look something like this.

```
@echo off
set "Branch=%~1"
if /I "%Branch%"=="refs/topics/" (
    echo yes
) else (
     echo no
)
```

But maybe you are looking to see if the first 12 characters of your input is equal to your string.

```
@echo off
set "Branch=%~1"
if /I "%Branch:~0,12%"=="refs/topics/" (
    echo yes
) else (
     echo no
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work (untested), given that the part the `*` stands for does not contain `/` or `\`:

```cmd
set "Branch=%~1"
for %%I in ("\%Branch:/=\%") do (
    if /I "%%~pI"=="\refs\topics\" (
        echo yes
    ) else (
        echo no
    )
)
```